# Toggle(hide/show) between a unknown number of div containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

An example use case would be a registration form that was split into several steps. I.e. there are three steps:

- Container 1 is visible
- Container 2 is hidden
- Container 3 is hidden

User clicks **next** button:

- Container 1 is hidden
- Container 2 is visible
- Container 3 is hidden

User clicks **next** button:

- Container 1 is hidden
- Container 2 is hidden
- Container 3 is visible

User clicks **previous** button:

- Container 1 is hidden
- Container 2 is visible
- Container 3 is hidden

and so on. This is what I tried:

```
$('#btn-next-step').live('click', function(){
    $('.form-step').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $(this).hide();
        }else{
            $(this).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="container-fluid form-step form-step1">
        step1
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid form-step form-step2">
        step2
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid form-step form-step3">
        step3   
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feFcu/

Can you help me with the logic. Any ideas how to realize this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, store the visible one in a variable. Then hide all of them, and use  [`.next('.form-step')`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the one that follows the previously visible one, and `.show()` it.

```
$('#step').on('click', function(){
    // Find the visible one and store in a variable
    var showing = $('.form-step:visible');
    // Hide all of them (including the currently visible one)
    $('.form-step').hide();
    // Find the next one with .next() and make it visible
    showing.next('.form-step').show();            
 });​
```

#### [Here is the updated jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/feFcu/3/)

Note that I have replaced `.live()` with `.on()`, since `.live()` [is now deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 0):

using this line will provide you with an array of the steps:

```
var steps = document.getElementsByClassName('.form-step');
```

now you can itterate through the steps by tracking which step is active with a seperate variable.